# Where does the REST API developed at server or client?

Tags: android, rest, jakarta-ee, quora

I am a bit confused while developing the REST API. Where does actually this API developed.
Lets say, I have an android app and a Java based web app so the question is where am I suppose to develop this REST which will give me an access to my MySQL database in android app or on the server which will "produce" the JSON?

Also how does the mobile apps like Quora or FB consumes such a large data from server in a short time of period. Do they use REST?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

Answer (score 1):

It is implemented at both sides, at the server the server side (processing requests and sending responses), and at the client the client side (sending requests and processing responses).

Comment: can you give me an example with an android app? what steps do I need to follow on server side and in android?

Comment: This is far too broad to answer on SO. Look for a tutorial.

Comment: @Henry - yes, too broad - vote to close for that reason and move your answer to the comments :)